# Python package to describe settings

Tags: python, configuration, package, settings, markup

I have a number of configuration parameters for my project, and would like a way to generically build a user interface that will handle the type of each of the parameters appropriately.

To start with, I figure each parameter must contain some meta-data about it's type and allowable values. I feel that this problem must have been solved a thousand times and there must even be some sort of package which will handle some sort of markdown language for my parameters.

If I had to write it myself, it would start with something that looked like:

```
class Parameter(object):
    def __init__(param_type, value, desc):
        self.param_type = param_type
        self.value = value


class NumericParameter(Parameter):
    def __init__(value, min_lim=None, max_lim=None, desc=""):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__(self.__class__,value,desc)
        self.min_lim = min_lim
        self.max_lim = max_lim

class EnumParameter(Parameter):
    def __init__(value, enum=[], desc=""):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__(self.__class__,value,desc)
        self.enum=enum

class MySettings():
    def __init__():
        settings = dict()
        settings['Mode']=EnumParameter('Contiuous',['Continuous','Finite','Single Point'],'Set the termination condition')
        settings['NumSamples']=NumericParameter(100,min_lim=0)
   .
   .
   .
```

but it really feels like I'm reinventing the wheel...or at least the transmission.